# StaticResource lookup in merged dictionaries

Tags: wpf, styles, staticresource

I have been reading and trying a lot and I still couldn't find a answer to my problem. So I really hope that you guys can help me out.

If I have one TopLevel Dictionary, and a color dictionary and a style dictionary.

TopLevelDictionary.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:Base="clr-namespace:Hamilton.XRP2.Base;assembly=Hamilton.XRP2.Base.BaseUI">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ColorDictionary.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Controls/Button.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

If I use in Button.xaml a resource from ColorDictionary.xaml why does static resource not work? It should, shouldn't it? Why do I have to merge ColorDictionary into my control style dictionary? If I have like 70 Base Controls every base control has to merge the color dictionary, I don't know why but that slows down my application enormously!

Can anybody advice me on how to do this the right way?

Regards,
m00ni

Comment: What is the error when you try to set it as static?

Comment: That StaticResource Lookup failed. The resource cannot be found.